# I cant see any payload in LOG mediator with level = full after CALL mediator in WSO2 6.6.0

Tags: json, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I need help, because I'm already losing faith ))
I have a very simple API, which is built on the wso2.
Here is my API code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/dwh" name="dwhCallEp" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/ep/{sysparam}">
        <inSequence>
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="START" value="call into dwh storage"/>
                <property expression="get-property('uri.var.sysparam')" name="sysparam"/>
            </log>
            <call>
                <endpoint>
                    <http method="get" statistics="enable" trace="enable" uri-template="http://my_path?sysparam={uri.var.sysparam}&amp;call_in_async_mode=false">
                        <timeout>
                            <duration>120000</duration>
                            <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
                        </timeout>
                        <suspendOnFailure>
                            <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                            <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
                        </suspendOnFailure>
                        <markForSuspension>
                            <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                        </markForSuspension>
                    </http>
                </endpoint>
            </call>
            <property expression="json-eval($[0])" name="JsonPayload" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <log level="full" separator="&#xa;">
                <property expression="$ctx:JsonPayload" name="JsonPayload"/>
            </log>
            <script language="js"><![CDATA[var payload = mc.getPayloadJSON();
                    var log = mc.getServiceLog();
                    log.info("payload_json : " + payload);
                    log.info("payload_json : " + JSON.stringify(payload));
                    mc.setProperty("payload_json",JSON.stringify(payload));]]></script>
            <log level="full" separator="&#xa;">
                <property name="payload" expression="json-eval($)" />
            </log>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence>
            <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                <format>
                    <error>$1</error>
                </format>
                <args>
                    <arg value="something go wrong!!!"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
        </faultSequence>
    </resource>
</api>
```

I have tried to get the response body in different ways :

- using log level="full" to see everything that was returned by my API after call mediator
- using expression="json-eval($[0])" in property mediator and then write its value to the log
- using script mediator to try to get the payload as mc.getPayloadJSON() and then using JSON.stringify(payload) to get the body string and writing it to a property
- using expression="json-eval($)" in property mediator and then write its value to the log

But none of the methods gave any result.

This is a stack from my logs :

```
[2024-02-01 11:07:51,198]  INFO {LogMediator} - {api:dwhCallEp} START = call into dwh storage, sysparam = pn_citytypes
[2024-02-01 11:07:51,201]  INFO {TRACE_LOGGER} - Sending message through endpoint : null resolving to address = http://erp.ukrposhta.loc/ws/api/_MR_DWH_KATALOG?sysparam={uri.var.sysparam}&call_in_async_mode=false
[2024-02-01 11:07:51,201]  INFO {TRACE_LOGGER} - SOAPAction: null
[2024-02-01 11:07:51,201]  INFO {TRACE_LOGGER} - WSA-Action: null
[2024-02-01 11:07:51,208]  INFO {TimeoutHandler} - This engine will expire all callbacks after GLOBAL_TIMEOUT: 120 seconds, irrespective of the timeout action, after the specified or optional timeout
[2024-02-01 11:07:51,254]  INFO {LogMediator} - {api:dwhCallEp} To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous
WSAction: 
SOAPAction: 
MessageID: urn:uuid:d16a7929-5a73-4bd9-9a52-d2431aed680b
correlation_id: 04c91129-739e-4628-a206-ddb3bb047bc1
Direction: request
JsonPayload = 
Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body/></soapenv:Envelope>
[2024-02-01 11:07:51,273]  INFO {CommonScriptMessageContext} - payload_json : [object Object]
[2024-02-01 11:07:51,274]  INFO {CommonScriptMessageContext} - payload_json : {}
[2024-02-01 11:07:51,275]  INFO {LogMediator} - {api:dwhCallEp} To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous
WSAction: 
SOAPAction: 
MessageID: urn:uuid:d16a7929-5a73-4bd9-9a52-d2431aed680b
correlation_id: 04c91129-739e-4628-a206-ddb3bb047bc1
Direction: request
payload = 
Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body/></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Either way, I was getting an empty body as the payload or in the script mediator [object Object].

But Postman returned the payload I should have gotten in my code :

[image: Postman result]

What is wrong ?

Comment: WHy is the call in Postman is different from the actual call? `http://erp.ukrposhta.loc/ws/api/_MR_DWH_KATALOG?sysparam={uri.var.sysparam}&call_in_async_mode=false`

Comment: Because in Postman i used the API`s url from wso2 ei (url of my service) , and in the CALL mediator i used the link, that had to get me the body that i was waiting

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding the certificate to the keystore of wso2 ei and using the `https://...` request in the EP in the CALL mediator instead of `http://` request.
That's why i couldn't write the payload value in the service.
Why Postman could do that with `http://...` and get the response, i have no idea ?